# input shape error train some data with resnet keras

Tags: neural-network, keras, conv-neural-network, resnet

I'm trying to train some data with CNN.

```
   x_train.shape
    (67197, 99, 81, 1)
   y_train.shape
    (67197, 12)
```

and trying to use Keras's Resnet method

```
import keras
import keras_resnet.models

input_shape = (98,81,1)
nclass = 12

    x = keras.layers.Input(input_shape)
    model = keras_resnet.models.ResNet50(x,classes=nclass)
    model.compile("adam","categorical_crossentropy",["accuracy"])
    model.fit(x_train,y_train,
             batch_size = 300,
             nb_epoch=5,
             validation_data = (x_test,y_test),
             shuffle = True,
             )
```

but I got some shape error.

```
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected input_3 to have shape (None, 98, 81, 1) but got array with shape (67197, 99, 81, 1)
```

Comment: If the answer resolved your issue, kindly accept it (answers take up valuable time for respondents)

Answer (score 0):

Its just a typo, your training data has shape (samples, 99, 81, 1), so the input shape should be (99, 81, 1), not (98, 81, 1). Its just off by one.